# Sequelize 1:n association

Tags: sequelize.js

I have following tables:

```
--Cable--
|id|name|

--Cable_Part--
|id|fk_cable|data|
```

Example of data is:

```
Cable:
1 - Cable One

Cable_Part:
1 - 1 - Some data
2 - 1 - More data
3 - 1 - Even more data
```

I wish to retrieve each of these cable parts as a array/object in my query.
Ive tried following relation:

```
@Model.Cable.belongsToMany @Model.CablePart,
{
    through: 'cable_part'
    foreignKey: 'cable'
}
```

Im getting this error:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: CablePart (CablePart) is not associated to Cable!
```

Also, it seems that **hasMany** is deprecated as I'm getting this message if I'm attempting to use it

```
Using 2 x hasMany to represent N:M relations has been deprecated. Please use belongsToMany instead
```

I'm sure this association should be easy to make, but it seems like it doesnt work whatever I attempt to do.

The Query i'm attempting to do:

```
  that.Database.Model.Cable.all(
    include:
      [
        {
          model: that.Database.Model.CablePart
          as: 'CablePart'
        }
      ]

  ).then (cables)->
```

**EDIT:**
This is a 1:n not a n:m, using following mapping still gives an error:

```
@Model.CablePart.belongsTo @Model.Cable,
{
    foreignKey: 'cable'
}
@Model.Cable.hasMany @Model.CablePart,
{
    foreignKey: 'cable'
}
```

Error is:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`through` and `belongsToMany` are for n:m associations. `through` specifies the join table, so it is not needed in your case.

The `Include unexpected` error suggests that `that.Database.Model.CablePart` might be undefined. Also, remove the `as` part of the include - that is only needed if you specify `as` on the association

Comment: `that.Database.Model.CablePart` is not Undefined. But it seems to be a "bug" with sequelize _maybe_. It seems like it error's out whenever a Cable does not have any cable parts, as it works fine with following code `database.Model.Cable.find(
  {
    where:
      id: 4706
    include: [database.Model.CablePart]
  }
).then (parts) ->
  console.log parts`. I removed the "As" option, but it did not make any difference. Also attempted to add ´allowNull: true´in mapping without any luck.

Comment: That sounds weird - the error about unexpected includes is thrown before the query hits the database so it shouldn't matter whether there are any associated objects or not.

Comment: it seems like it fixed itself by simply restarting the database. I would no think this is a general solution however.